# Calling a function through a function pointer where arguments are not matching

Tags: pointers, function-pointers, rpc

while I was studying some RPC stub routines C source files generated by RPCGEN -a msg.x in Unix. I come upon some function pointer that confuses me.

In the server stub file - msg_svc.c, there is a declaration like

```
char *(*local)();
```

which declares a pointer to a function that takes no arguments and returns a char pointer

In the server file - msg_server.c, there is a function defined as

```
savemsg_1(argp, rqstp)
    char **argp;
    struct svc_req *rqstp;
{
     some code
}
```

Back to the server stub file - msg_svc.c, I see codes that do function pointer casting

```
local = (char *(*)()) savemsg_1;
```

And called later by

```
result = (*local)(&argument, rqstp);
```

where argument and rqstp is defined by

```
union {
    char *savemsg_1_arg;
    int readmsg_1_arg;
} argument;
```

And

```
struct svc_req *rqstp;
```

My question is why does this work? I've done research on google/stackoverflow on function pointers. After casting to a function pointer that does not accept any arguments, and calling the function throught that function pointer with mismatch arguments(accepting 2 arguments in this case) should generate undefined behavior.

The source is located at [msg_svc.c](http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~jia/C/rpc/demo/msg_svc.c)

I would really appreciate any inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is Undefined Behavior. However, one possible result of Undefined Behavior is the behavior that you intended.

In particular, the ancient C code generated (for `savemsg_1`) makes it clear that this is intended to be comiled by very old, very simple compilers. They're fairly predicatable, don't use registers for argument passing, etcetera. That increases the probability that the code works. But "it *probably* works" really isn't an achievement. Don't write this kind of code yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That clears it up. I wonder if there is better solution when dealing with such cases where a function pointer variable could be storing different function with different arguments.